# Is there a list of hot-spots and free wifis in Germany?

Tags: germany, data-request

Is there a list or database or API for finding hot-spots and public available wifis for Germany?

Of course this data is volatile, so it should be often actualized.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Database of free WiFi hotspots](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4855/database-of-free-wifi-hotspots)

Comment: There are German-specific initiatives, so I would not consider this question as a duplicate just because a wider question exist.

Answer (score 2):

There is a wiki at http://freewifiwiki.net/index.php?title=Germany which is a listing (not a database).  There are links at the bottom of that site to additional sites in German and English appear to augment this overarching listing.

Answer (score 2):

In Germany there is an initiative called "Freifunk", which sets up free wifi networks everywhere. At the moment (August 2015) there are about 17K hotspots. There is a [map](http://www.freifunk-karte.de/) showing all (public) hotspots and there are some [APIs](http://freifunk.net/blog/2013/12/die-freifunk-api/) to get the data.
The advantage of Freifunk is that it doesn't require a registration and it's uncensored.