# Database of free WiFi hotspots

Tags: data-request, geospatial, internet

I want to create an [app that shows free WiFi hotspots around you](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18145/android-offline-app-that-shows-free-wifi-hotspots), even if you have no Internet connection yet.

So, I need a **re-distributable database of free WiFi hotspots** for the whole world.

- For each hotspot, I just need its latitude/longitude.
- Hotspots that are free but require user registration or terms approval should either be excluded or have metadata indicating that.

---

*http://freewifiwiki.net has hotspots info, but each hotspot is only a line of free text, often including an address but it would be difficult for a program to split address and prose.*

Comment: Your app would get great coverage if users could automatically upload open WiFi details with a button push (SSID, latitude and longitiude).

Comment: @philshem: Yes, and that would be a great way to contribute back, if this data is found to be reliable :-) (GPS is often rather inaccurate, so I might have to wait for several people to push the same hotspot before considering it as reliable)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the coverage is very complete, but [Open Street Maps](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) has a key called **[internet_access](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:internet_access)**.

With this key you can use tags like **[wlan](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:internet_access%3Dwlan)** to find open WLAN.

To find free WLAN, add the `internet_access:fee=no` option

Answer (score 2):

Look at [freifunk-karte.de](http://freifunk-karte.de) there are 12k Hotspots in Germany. You should find the API and the JSONs at http://api.freifunk.net