# US Wifi Hotspots

Tags: geospatial, usa

Looking for US Wifi open geospatial data; I read through all of the wifi tagged questions including [database of wifi hotspots](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4855/database-of-free-wifi-hotspots) but feels like this is unique enough and could use some refreshing.
[Here's a Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Hf-2oJ12uGurtV23gSQhLxCWR13j3u_sTbL27pDhVHI/edit) of community effort so far and [the tweet behind this question](https://twitter.com/kshuyler/status/1255586496452726785).
I'll add the content from the Google Doc with any answers received here.
[Inspired by this map of Wifi in Virginia](https://virginiatech.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=825546b05bba47048470e1cfa7364de3)

Answer (score 1):

[New York City WiFi Hotspots](https://www.kaggle.com/new-york-city/nyc-public-wifi)

Every public WiFi hotspot in New York City.

This dataset is now hosted and updated daily [here](https://www.kaggle.com/new-york-city/nyc-wi-fi-hotspot-locations)

The dataset consists of records for every public WiFi hotspot (ones provided by or in partnership with the city) in New York City. It contains over 2500 records overall, and is current as of August 11, 2017.

---

[NYC Wi-Fi Hotspot Locations](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/NYC-Wi-Fi-Hotspot-Locations/yjub-udmw)

---

[data.gov.uk | Find open data](https://data.gov.uk/search?q=wifi%20hotspot)